# pyautogui mover mouse desde su posicion y aumentarla

Tags: python

estoy usando pyautogui y una funcion llamada pos = pyautogui.position() la cual obtiene la posicion del mouse, y si uso pyautogui.moveTo(pos) se queda igual porque es la misma posicion, lo que quiero es sumarle a pos en X o en Y, por ejemplo pyautogui.moveTo(pos, x+1), se que pos, x+1 no existe pero se entiende.

Comment: Podrías insertar el código que llevas realizado hasta la fecha? Eso ayudaría a entender tu problema y que se te pueda ayudar con mayor facilidad.

Answer (score 0):

La función **pyautogui.position()** devuelve dos valores. Cuando haces:

```
pos = pyautogui.position()
```

Recibes el valor x e y de la posición y lo guardas en la variable **pos*. Sería similar a esto:

```
x, y = pyautogui.position()
```

En el primer ejemplo pos va a contener una coordenada x y otra y. Por ejemplo pos = 50, 100
De igual manera la función **pyautogui.moveTo()** toma como argumento dos valores.

```
pyautogui.moveTo(x,y)
```

O en tu caso:

```
pyautogui.moveTo(pos)
```

Si quieres cambiar alguno de los dos valores guardados dentro de pos puedes usar sus indices para acceder a ellos y cambiarlos.
Por ejemplo

```
pyautogui.moveTo(pos[0]+50, pos[1]+75)
```

Al escribir pos[0] el interprete entiende que re refieres al primer elemento de la pareja (x, y), y en pos[1] tienes el segundo elemento.

Comment: Podrías usar el comando moveRel para evitar hacer esa suma (supongo que se hace internamente). Algo así como pyautogui.moveRel(50, 75)